# Prevent fork() from duplicating memory mapping of the process (mmap'ed)

Tags: linux, memory-management, fork, linux-device-driver, mmap

I Have a Linux device driver that implements mmap sets of operations (vm_operations),
And a process which memory maps the device driver memory space using mmap calls.

The process sometimes call fork() to perform a task and then destroy the child process.
this is causing extensive use of mmap calls on the child processes to duplicate the memory maps of the parent.

I want to avoid these duplications and actually make all the memory maps private to the parent only.

Is this possible on Linux ?

Comment: Perhaps you need [`clone(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone).

Comment: What flags are you passing to `mmap(2)`? What kind of memory accesses does the child process do?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis - unfortunatelyi cannot control the fork() calls on the main process... I can only change my device driver behaivor

Comment: @Ulfalizer - The child process does not access the memory, but still mmap_open/mmap_close are called when the child forks/exits

Comment: @ItayMarom: Not sure if that can be avoided. Memory mappings are always inherited by child processes (with either the same pages if `MAP_SHARED` is used or copy-on-write semantics if `MAP_PRIVATE` is used). My guess (not an expert here) is that `vm_operations_struct`'s `open()` and `close()` will be called in either case. Maybe you need to make `open()` and `close()` cheap and load stuff lazily as you get page faults.

Comment: @Ulfalizer: Memory mappings of the parent process are always inherited when using `fork`. If OP can't change userspace code, the only options available are hackish "make-an-exception-for-this process" things.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: Yeah, already said that :). `grep`'ing around the kernel a bit, many drivers seem to do the work in `.fault` and either leave out `.open` and `.close` completely or keep them trivial (e.g., reference counting stuff), so maybe that's the intended approach.

Comment: Yeah, i am also thinking about moving the work to the page fault handler...
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The duplication of a mapping can be avoided by calling `madvise(address, length, MADV_DONTFORK)` on the memory mapping in question before calling `fork`.